# Who decides what is ochel nefesh for Yom Tov?

Tags: melacha-creative-work, yom-tov, ochel-nefesh

Ochel nefesh [supposedly](https://www.ou.org/torah/parsha/rabbi-fox-on-parsha/parshat_vayakhel_the_prohibition_against_melachah_on_shabbat_and_yom_tov/) refers to the permissibility during Yom Tov of doing melachos that "cause personal pleasure."

"Personal"? Really?

No, of course not; it's after all [the rabbis](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Which_Melachot_are_forbidden_on_Yom_Tov%3F#cite_note-1) who decide what "personal pleasure" is, or is supposed to be. *(@Msh210 notes: "I don't think it means 'pleasure to your person'. I think it means 'pleasure of the person (body)' as opposed to intellectual or other pleasure.")*
However, do one's own tastes and responses enter the halachic picture at *all*? That is, if something--let's say, taking a bath--gave me great pleasure, but involved doing a melacha during Yom Tov, could there be any halachic justification for doing it even if it is not on the [official list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20439/1516)?   Inversely, if I hated a particular food, would I be allowed to prepare it for myself during Yom Tov in the name of ochel nefesh?

For the sake of argument, let's assume we are talking about rabbinically-defined melachos rather than Biblical ones.

Related (please don't judge harshly; this is a real problem for me): [How to have an easier time with Yom Tov?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65685/how-to-have-an-easier-time-with-yom-tov)

Related: [Borer and Grinding on Yom Tov - and other Melachoth that are Ochel Nefesh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20430/borer-and-grinding-on-yom-tov-and-other-melachoth-that-are-ochel-nefesh#comment48235_20430)

Comment: Try searching for the terms Shaveh LeKhol Nefesh. You'll likely see this discussed in the context of smoking on YT.

Comment: @DoubleAA But does that actually involve a melacha?

Comment: Smoking? Certainly. Burning fire.

Comment: This is a good question. In general *halakha* reflects the need of all people, not individual needs. When something *shave lekol nefesh* (important to most people) is permitted (e.g., using water heated for food on yom tov for other uses, see second part [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98543/11501)), the fact one person might have different preferences is not taken into account